# Create a textbox with "smart" password char

Tags: c#, multithreading, textbox, compact-framework

I'm using .NET 3.5 CF and trying to create a textbox which should hide the character written inside it. This works by setting the parameter PasswordChar to = "*". However this change the char to a * directly.

What I want is a "smart" textbox who change the character to a * after a delay (approximate 1 second) which will make the user to get some feedback that correct character was written.

I tried this by creating another thread that should handle this since the user should still be able to write more characters and not wait this delay. I did something like this:

```
                if (UseModernPasswordScreenMaskning)
                {
                    this.Invoke(new UpdateTextCallback(this.UpdateText), new object[]{"*"});
                }

     private void UpdateText(string text)
    {
        int k = this.Text.Length;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        this.Text = this.Text.Remove(k - 1, 1);
        this.Text = this.Text.Insert(k - 1, "*");
    }
```

It works but the sleep is on my current thread which make next letter written delay by 1 second before it shows up. I want each letter to show directly and change to a *, 1 second after that particular char was written.

Answer (score 1):

As i understand, a "smart" password textbox is

1. the last character will become * within 1s
2. if user type a new character, the older one will become * (although it doesn't last 1s)

So

1. Create a timer callback with 1s interval to change last character to *
2. In smartTextBox_TextChanged event, change the previous character to *

Here is my code

```
public void Do(object state)
    {
        int num = this.textBox1.Text.Count();
        if (num > 0)
        {
            StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(this.textBox1.Text);

            s[num - 1] = '*';
            this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                this.textBox1.Text = s.ToString();
                this.textBox1.SelectionStart = this.textBox1.Text.Count();
                timer.Dispose();
                timer = null;
            }));
        }
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (timer == null)
        {
            timer = new System.Threading.Timer(timerCallback, null, 1000, 1000);
        }
        int num = this.textBox1.Text.Count();
        if (num > 1)
        {
            StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(this.textBox1.Text);
            s[num - 2] = '*';
            this.textBox1.Text = s.ToString();
            this.textBox1.SelectionStart = num;                   
        }
    }
```

In initialize

```
timerCallback = new TimerCallback(Do);
```

Comment: Thanks!, however when doing like you suggested i get an error when the code is inside the "Do" function. "Control.Invoke" must be used to interact with controls created on a separate thread". This i want i want it to do, but not sure how to do it. The textbox is created in same thread which is an issue.

Comment: i run this code again and can't see any problems, that's weird

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it by adding since the line "int num = this.textBox1.Text.Count();"  could not be used before that statement:

```
    public void Do(object state)
    {
        if (this.logonPwTxtBox.InvokeRequired)
        { .. }
     }
```