# C# WinForms smart password textbox class

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, passwords

I am using c# winforms (.NET 4,0) and I would like to create a "smart" password textbox class (or UserControl) that shows the entered character for a time then masks the character.  I looked at this post: [Create a textbox with "smart" password char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20681813/create-a-textbox-with-smart-password-char) and the solution works great, but is done in the Form class.  I would like all of the functionality to be in a class or user control so it can simply be dropped onto a form.

My class using the above referenced solution:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

/// <summary>
/// TODO: Update summary.
/// </summary>
public class SmartTextBox : TextBox
{
    public SmartTextBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    #region Component Designer generated code
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        // 
        // SmartTextBox
        // 
        this.TextChanged += new EventHandler(SmartTextBox_TextChanged);
    }
    #endregion

    System.Threading.Timer timer = null;
    void SmartTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnTextChanged(e);
        if (timer == null)
        {
            timer = new System.Threading.Timer(new TimerCallback(Do), null, 1000, 1000);
        }
        SmartTextBox tb = this as SmartTextBox;
        int num = tb.Text.Length;
        if (num > 1)
        {
            StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(tb.Text);
            s[num - 2] = '*';
            tb.Text = s.ToString();
            tb.SelectionStart = num;
            //Debug.WriteLine("TextChanged: " + tb.Text);
        }
    }
    public void Do(object state)
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            int num = this.Text.Length;
            if (num > 0)
            {
                StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(this.Text);

                s[num - 1] = '*';
                this.Invoke(new Action(() =>                //  <----Error on this line
                {
                    this.Text = s.ToString();
                    this.SelectionStart = this.Text.Length;
                    timer.Dispose();
                    timer = null;
                }));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I try to compile I get the following error:
 error CS0305: Using the generic type 'System.Action' requires 1 type arguments

I am not sure how to resolve this error, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you're targeting .NET 4? See here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263626/action-delegate-in-net2-using-the-generic-type-system-actiont-requires-1

Comment: Well now don't I feel like an idiot.  Good catch, I set it to .NET4 and with a few other changes it compiles and works as expected.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @JonB could you put that as an answer so we can remove this question from the open list?

Comment: @NickUdell let's flag this as a dupe instead.

Answer (score -1):

Change this line:

```
this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
```

To:

```
this.Invoke(new Action(delegate()
```